# Is it possible to create a Encrypted Sqlite Database?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, encryption

Is it possible to create an encrypted sqlite database. is possible to use **Encryption On** key word in Sqlite database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is possible - sounds like performance-killer or poor encryption. Neither is desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/), which supports, among others, Java.